# How to get <select> <option> to work on IOS

Tags: php, jquery, iphone, forms, ipad

I have read a lot about the following issue and cannot find a solution so i'm asking for some guidance please :)

http://www.livelovematernity.com/maternity-jeans/ has a dropdown sorting menu [filter].
This works for all browsers except for Safari, iPad and iPhone (IOS).

On IOS, when i select a sort from the [filter] it doesn't work at all, has anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: Works fine on iPad 2 iOS 6.1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, are you selecting from the dropdown menu named: Filter: ?

Comment: Yes.. I also tested on iOS 5, safari browser, also works fine.

Comment: That's really odd, i'm even more confused now :(. I also tested it on Safari 5.1.7, Ipad 2 and iPhone 5 and none work for me.

Comment: Can anyone else see the same issues as i can?